# python-docx replace string with saving style

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

Is there any way to save paragraph style during string replacement?

```
from docx import Document


doc = Document('source.docx')
for p in doc.paragraphs:
    if 'some text' in p.text:
        text = p.text.replace('some text', 'new text')
        style = p.style
        p.text = text
        p.style = style

doc.save('dest.docx')
```

This code replaces string but change font style and back ground color.